# Update whole document except specified fields

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I have a document that I need to update. However, in the old doc there might be one field that I want to exclude from the update and keep.

How can I achieve this?

In the example below, the *old* `positions`doc might include a field `primary`which I want to keep between updates.

```
Meteor.users.update(
  {
    type: SI.ENUM.USER.TYPE.BROADCASTER,
    'positions._id': this.previous._id
  },
  {
    $set: {'positions.$': doc}
  },
  {
    multi: true
  }
);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To update only specific elements of sub-document in array you have to use the positional operator on the fields of sub-document.

```
Meteor.users.update(
    {
        type: SI.ENUM.USER.TYPE.BROADCASTER,
        'positions._id': this.previous._id
    },
    {
        $set: {'positions.$.foo': newFoo, 'positions.$.bar': newBar }
    },
    {
        multi: true
    }
);
```

This will update only the `foo` & `bar` fields of the sub-document in array.

If you have the values available as object in variable `doc`, you can do the following:

```
var keys = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(doc);
var newDoc = {}
keys.forEach(key => {
    newDoc['positions.$.' + key] = doc[key];
});

Meteor.users.update(
    {
        type: SI.ENUM.USER.TYPE.BROADCASTER,
        'positions._id': this.previous._id
    },
    {
        $set: newDoc
    },
    {
        multi: true
    }
);
```

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I was hoping there might be a Mongo operator, but that does the trick as well.

Answer (score 0):

```
findPositionAndUpdate: async(req, res, next) => {
    let setObj = {};
    Object.keys(req.body).forEach(key => {
        if (key != "_id") {
            setObj["positions.$." + key] = req.body[key];
        }
    });
    let response = await Meteor.users.updateOne({ "positions._id": req.params.positionId }, {
        $set: setObj
    });
}
```

If you are thinking to automate your request body, you can use above script, as I came to this post searching for something like above. My implementation is in nodejs ;-)